# Count operations in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, count

"Count operations are limited to 160 count queries / minute period for each application. The limit applies to all requests made by all clients of the application".
Sorry but i haven't understand very well what it means. This limit refers to a single app on a single device ? Or if i have 160 clients they can do only 1 request per minute?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This limit is per app, all users of your app can make 160 count queries a minute in total, so yes, with 160 users you would get 1 count query per user/minute.

In general, you should avoid count queries altogether and instead use counters to keep track of counts. This however depends on what you are doing and would be out of scope of your question itself.